# Clementine skips songs on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: clementine, amarok

So I've installed Clementine and it seems to be skipping songs with an error message "Failed to parse stream". I've tried Amarok, but it does the same.

No idea what to do here. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, the names of folders have bracket characters. I removed these characters and that solved my problem. I don't know if this is the problem in your case.